# Trouble creating webpage layout with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am creating an angular app and i have created a layout but i am having some trouble with its functionality.

currently the header stays fixed in position as does the activator but the menu appearing on rollover does not and when scrolling the content in the body appears over the top of the header. i am not fantastic at css but know some. any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated :)

[image: This is how the layout looks]

[image: this is how i would like the menu to appear]

again any help at all would be fantastic.

Comment: any code you have done? or any jsfiddle will do

Comment: Part of the problem sounds like z-index needs to be higher on the header, but please, let us see a fiddle or some code!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kyu0x9ym/
it has somehow developed a new problem of the menu bar appearing over the header despite me not changing anything :s 
sorry its very clear guys :/
Thanks George i actually tried z index to no avail

Comment: you could also add `translate` and `transition` to make the change from hidden to visible more smooth :) https://jsfiddle.net/amwill/kyu0x9ym/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the `z-index` property to the header class it puts the header over the activator.

```
.ts-header {
    height: 74px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999; /* NEW */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kyu0x9ym/1/

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for your help. basically what i want is the exact layout of the first picture where only the content in the block with the text "Only the content..." scrolls while the header and the side bar remain fixed in position and the side bar below the header. Currently the content in the body block appears over the header when scrolled.

Comment: thanks michael and cocoa thats close enough to what i would like im sure ill be able to figure the rest out myself. thanks a lot for your help :)